# Column Spanning in ag grid exported excel

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have been trying to implement export to excel functionality in ag grid

In ag-grid,for a particular scenario I am doing colSpan for 13 columns and showing data in rest 2 columns.
I am able to show custom data in columns using processcellCallBack.
However,when I am doing export to excel ,colSpan is not maintained in exported excel and custom data is shown repeatedly in all 13 columns.

I tried using ColumKeys but seems it can't be used conditionally

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Code Snapshot]

[image: Excel Result]

Comment: it will help if you post some relevant code

Comment: @PratikBhat...I have added the screenshots of the relevant code and the excel I am getting.

Comment: I dont see any screenshots

Comment: @PratikBhat...Please Check now.